# How do I express a "has many through" relationship in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am attempting to use Entity Framework 5 to query an existing MySQL database. I used code-first to create a code-based model that maps to an existing database following [this tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620).

I have two tables: `users` and `buddies`. A `User` has an `id`, a `name` and an `email`. A `Buddy` has a `user_id` and a `buddy_id`. A `User` has many `Buddies` (which are also `Users`). The `buddy_id` column is a foreign key back into the `Users` table. So each `User` has many `Users` through `Buddies`.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IList<User> Buddies { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my database access code:

```
using (var db = new Models.fooContext())
{
    foreach (Models.user user in db.users)
    {
        var u = new User
        {
            Id      = user.id,
            Name    = user.name,
            Email   = user.email,
            Buddies = new List<User>()
        };

        // this is obviously very inefficient but I am just
        // trying to get anything to work
        foreach (Models.buddy buddy in db.buddies) // this line throws an exception
        {
            if (buddy.user_id == user.id)
            {
                var b = new User();
                // take buddy.user_id and find this user in the user table
                u.Buddies.Add(b);
            }
        }

        // serialize User and write it to a file here
    }
}
```

This code throws the following exception on the line indicated above:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: an error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

The inner exception is a `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException` with the message

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

My questions:

1. How do I create a relationship that tells EF that each `User` has many `Buddies`?
2. Once EF understands that a `User` has many `Buddies`, how do I use the `buddy_id` to find the `User` record for that `Buddy`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have one data type that you are calling separate names. That is a little confusing. However To get this to work with code first you just need the following fluent configuration in your Custom DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<user>().
      HasMany(c => c.Buddies).
      WithMany().
      Map(
       m =>
       {
          m.MapLeftKey("user_id");
          m.MapRightKey("buddy_id");
          m.ToTable("buddies");
       });
}
```

This assuming your user class looks like this:

```
[Table("user")]
public class user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public virtual List<user> Buddies { get; set; }
}
```

If you use the above method every user object you have will have a **navigation property** on it called Buddies. When querying for users you will want to **eager load buddy users**, do:

```
context.users.Include("Buddies")
```

Further, To address your issue with multiple readers. It is because you have not **enumerated the query** (db.users) from your first loop. To address that you can enumerate the query like so:

```
var users = context.users.Include("Buddies").ToList();
foreach(var user in users)....
```

And if you use the configuration above, you don't need to try and match id's you simply acquire the list (null field if new) of buddies from the user using the buddies **navigation property** (virtual,lazy loaded), do:

```
user.Buddies
```

As you can see you don't really need a 'Model.buddy' (since it only contains an id mapping)
Entity framework will take care of the linking. However if you're not always including the Buddies in your user query you may want the table. Which would be queried with LINQ in the following way:

```
var userBuddies = db.buddies.Where(buddy=>buddy.user_id == user.id).ToList();
//An enumerated list of user buddies 
//do stuff
```

Comment: Excellent, in-depth, actionable answer.  The relationships now work fine.  The only problem that I am encountering now is that the tables are large.  By including "Buddies" an OUTER JOIN is performed and the result is too large.  Can Buddies be loaded lazily on a per-User basis?

Comment: Indeed, Entity-Framework Is very excellent in this area. Though if not understood it can lead to issues with serialization or any sort of reflection. When you query your users without the `Include(..)` Your buddies list is returned, with metadata, but no actual data. When you want access it or iterate over it, the dynamic proxy will query the database. You can also invoke a query manually by calling `ToList()`. I recommend reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)