# EF 6 - Recursive Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In my domain i have the concept of a `Group` and `User`. A `User` is a `Guid`,login and password, and a `Group` is composed by a `Guid`,Title and a List of "members". The members of a given group can be both `Users` and others `Groups`. How do model this scenario in EF 6 using code-first?

Comment: You need to setup the fluent configuration. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550923/how-do-i-express-a-has-many-through-relationship-in-entity-framework-5/19555379#19555379)

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class which both `User` and `Group` extend (maybe containing only the `[Key]` attribute) and use it. EF will create 3 tables and handle the joins...