# How to get List of items in item model using Include

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, eager-loading

`enter code here`I want to show a list of AppPlatforms in model, i have 4 tables App, AppPlatforms, Reviews, AppsArtifacts they have relationship. So i want to retrieve App data as well as AppPlatforms (like iOS and Android) of that App and then in AppPlatforms i want collections of Reviews and AppArtifacts.

i have used this code to include

when i use this

```
var app = dbContext.Apps
                  .Include("AppPlatforms.Reviews")
                  .Where(a => a.AppId == appId).ToList();
```

OR

```
var app = dbContext.Apps
                  .Include("AppPlatforms.Artifacts")
                  .Where(a => a.AppId == appId).ToList();
```

individually it is included, but when i use this

```
var app = dbContext.Apps
                  .Include("AppPlatforms.Reviews")
                  .Include("AppPlatforms.Artifacts")
                  .Where(a => a.AppId == appId).ToList();
```

then i got an error i.e InnerException = {"Unknown column 'Extent1.AppId' in 'on clause'"}

Here are my tables.

```
 public class App
    {
        [Key]
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActivated { get; set; }
        public bool? Status { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadedDate { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }

        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SubCategoryId")]
        public virtual SubCategory SubCategories { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppPlatform> AppPlatforms { get; set; }

    }


 public class AppPlatform
    {
        [Key]
        public int AppsPlatformId { get; set; }
        public string AlternativeName { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string DownloadLink { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public float FileSize { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AppId")]
        public virtual App App { get; set; }
        public int PlatformId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PlatformId")]
        public virtual Platform Platforms { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppsArtifact> Artifacts { get; set; }

    }


public class AppsArtifact
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AppsPlatformID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AppsPlatformID")]
        public virtual AppPlatform AppPlatform { get; set; }

        public int ArtifactId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ArtifactId")]
        public virtual Artifact Artifact { get; set; }
        public AppArtifactType Type { get; set; }
    }

 public class Review
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int Risk { get; set; }
        public ReviewStatus Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReviewDate { get; set; }

        public int? AppPlatformId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AppPlatformId")]
        public virtual AppPlatform AppPlatform { get; set; }

        public string ReviewerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ReviewerId")]
        public virtual IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
        public int LevelId { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(1)]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("LevelId")]
        public virtual Level Levels { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need relationships in the mapping? [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550923/how-do-i-express-a-has-many-through-relationship-in-entity-framework-5)

```
// Relationships
            this.HasMany(t => t.AppPlatforms)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("Table_AppPlatform");
                    m.MapLeftKey("IdLeft");
                    m.MapRightKey("IdRight");
                });
```

Comment: The relations are mapped using the `ForeignKey` attribute